# Can you send hierarchical logs to Graylog?

Tags: java, docker, graylog

I want to send hierarchical logs to Graylog. Something like :

- transactionId: 2a4c43ea-546a-4c31-afe6-4352446ef7ae Log: "start Instance"

  - transactionId: 50c45778-6c36-4d9f-93e6-5a7cf239ab61 Log: "query database"

"start Instance" would be the parent of "query database" and so on.

So far I did just a simple example, following this tutorial: [http://www.andrew-programming.com/2018/09/13/setup-graylog-on-local-machine-and-sent-logs-to-it-from-java-application/] sending some logs to Graylog like this:

```
 Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);
        logger.info("Application Start Running...");
        logger.debug("Application Start Running...");
        logger.error("Application Start Running...");
        logger.warn("Application Start Running...");
        logger.info("This a test");
```

But I need more then this. So basically I want to be able to send hierarchical logs , and also to be able to see them in Graylog UI as a hierarchy (this is very important to me and I am not sure this is possible). Can someone give some hints if this is possible and how?